# Function for stopping code (wehn terminal isn't active)

Tags: python, while-loop, terminal, keyboard, keyboard-events

Is there a function that can stop a while loop on keyboard input? Assume that the terminal or ide isn't active and thus if keyboard.is_pressed('e'): wouldn't work. This is not for a game.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it will work for you to have a KeyboardInterrupt i.e. by clicking "Ctrl+C", you can do it like this

```
def do_something():
    try:
        while True:
            print("In While!")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stop the loop!")
```

Comment: Wouldn't work. Only works if you have the ide or terminal as a active window. thanks for the attempt tho.